# How can I enable cors on openshift?

Tags: websocket, tomcat7, cors, openshift

I have an application that uses websocket. Websocket on openshift uses the 8000/8443 port. When I try to connect from js to ws I have a problem of cors because se website is on 80 port and websocket on 8000. How can I enable CORS on openshift?

Thank you!
aGO!

Comment: I already saw that but I can't believe that openshift doesn't allow the cors...

Comment: tell me if you have a solution, I also dont see the CORS headers in my openshift application and am still looking for the solution :(

Comment: Sorry but I don't have a solution...